# NodeJS on RaspberryPi 3 B error: gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio22/direction

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently working at a project in which I want to control a robot vehicle using a web application. I have chosen to build the application in node js and to host it on a Raspberry Pi 3 B. I installed npm and node js with its modules and everything works fine. I can see the web application form whatever device i want.

I was trying to use the npm module pi-gpio to control raspberry pi pins connected to the motors but I have an error:

> "gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of
>   /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio22/direction: No such file or
>   directory."

However, the application works perfectly fine. The only thing helpful that I found after few hours of research is the fact that the module might not work on the Raspberry PI 3 B.

Therefore the question is, did anyone do a similar project using the raspberry pi 3 B or anyone has any idea how can i solve this issue?

Thank you!
Regards,
Alex

Comment: Are you using Quickwire? https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio/issues/41

Comment: Yes I am. I managed to solve that error but now i face another one. `gpio-admin: could not flush data to /sys/class/gpio/export: Device or resource busy`